# What is the best way to expand macros inside keyval input in expl3

Tags: macros, expl3, expansion, key-value, l3keys

I think LaTeX packages rarely use macros as key names. And some users expect macros inside the keyval input will be expanded recursively first. But `l3keys` in `expl3` doesn't provide this functionality at this time. So it is a job of package writers. I can think of one way to do this. But it may be a little slow. Therefore I ask this question in hope of finding the best solution.

Note: only macros surrounded by commas are expanded inside keyval input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { test }
  {
    key1 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key2 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key3 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key4 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key5 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key6 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \mycommand {m}
  {
    \keys_set:nn { test } { #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\mycommand{key1=val1,key2=val2,key3=val3,key4=val4,key5=val5,key6=val6}

\def\mymacroa{key3=val3,key4=val4}

\mycommand{key1=val1,key2=val2,\mymacroa,key5=val5,key6=val6} % error

\def\mymacrob{key2=val2,\mymacroa,key5=val5}

\mycommand{key1=val1,\mymacrob,key6=val6} % error

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's just not possible, it remains possible to loop over the tokens and expand when it looks like a macro.

Comment: I think that is bad input which goes against the spirit of keyval. If people want to store some key combination they should use a meta key or a style.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer as far as I remember, there was a discussion with Joseph and Frank (and I added my two cents back then as well) to have one `f`-expansion in the code, which would allow this. Are these plans cancelled?

Comment: @Skillmon i vaguely remember something like that. I think it is still in the pipeline but i nevertheless prefer a style key.

Comment: Frank has asked us to look again at this: he'd like key names (but not values) to expand. I have code in hand but it needs proper review: there is a speed impact.

Comment: @Skillmon Just not been a top priority and needs careful review, so somewhat delayed

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you. I found the related pull request: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/pull/1048

Comment: @JosephWright I guess the f-expansion change will also apply to the new keyval option handler (in `\usepackage`)? Then it will benefit more packages.

Comment: @L.J.R. `\begin{advertisement}` not related to `l3keys`/`ltkeys`, but my own `expkv` has something "in the pipeline" as well, which would allow something similar with a dedicated syntax (somewhat like `expl3`'s `\exp_args:...` inside the key=value interface). `\end{advertisement}`

Comment: @L.J.R. Yes, the idea is to apply it within `\keyval_parse:nnN`, but like I said, not fully agreed yet

Comment: @JosephWright Will expansion take place while gathering from key=value-lists tokens belonging to keys or will expansion take place after having split the key apart? (The latter might allow denoting keys in terms of macros where the name of the key itself contains `=`. The further might allow macros yielding more key=value-pairs.)

Comment: @UlrichDiez plan is to `f`-expand as a first step, before splitting. Note that keys with `=` should already be possible by `{key=name} = {key=value}`.

Comment: I know others pointed this out already, but why...? Why not just add new keys instead of using macros that expand to keys?

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for clarification. I know about nesting key-names/key-values in braces. I mentioned for illustrating the difference depending on the moment in time when expansions are carried out.

Answer (score 4):

You can recursively scan the list of options, expanding once an item that's a single control sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l__ljr_keysexp_clist
\bool_new:N \l__ljr_keysexp_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ljr_keysexp_set:nn
 {
  \clist_clear:N \l__ljr_keysexp_set_clist
  % scan the options one by one and put them in a clist,
  % expanding once the control sequences that are found
  \bool_set_false:N \l__ljr_keysexp_bool
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \tl_if_single_p:n { ##1 } } { \token_if_cs_p:N ##1 }
     {
      \clist_put_right:No \l__ljr_keysexp_set_clist { ##1 }
      \bool_set_true:N \l__ljr_keysexp_bool
     }
     {
      \clist_put_right:Nn \l__ljr_keysexp_set_clist { ##1 }
     }
   }
  % we found a macro, let's repeat
  \bool_if:NTF \l__ljr_keysexp_bool
   {% there is a macro
    \ljr_keysexp_set:nV { #1 }\l__ljr_keysexp_set_clist
   }
   {% no macro, set the keys
    \keys_set:nV { #1 } \l__ljr_keysexp_set_clist
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \ljr_keysexp_set:nn { nV }

\keys_define:nn { test }
  {
    key1 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key2 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key3 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key4 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key5 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key6 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \mycommand {m}
  {
    \ljr_keysexp_set:nn { test } { #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mycommand{key1=val1,key2=val2,key3=val3,key4=val4,key5=val5,key6=val6}

\def\mymacroa{key3=val3,key4=val4}

\mycommand{key1=val1,key2=val2,\mymacroa,key5=val5,key6=val6} % error

\def\mymacrob{key2=val2,\mymacroa,key5=val5}

\mycommand{key1=val1,\mymacrob,key6=val6} % error

\end{document}
```

[image]

But it's not the best approach to key-value systems.

Answer (score 2):

*The following remarks do not answer your question, so probably don't upvote this "answer". The following remarks do not fit in a comment. They are intended to draw attention towards questions arising in the context.*

---

A list of tokens to be gathered alternately either for keys or for values, which - besides tokens undefined at the time of parsing/splitting the list but defined at the time of further processing the split (value-)components - can contain expandable tokens to be expanded only when not gathering for a value?

For gathering tokens for a key a tail-recursive loop is imaginable, which gathers non-expandable tokens as part of the key and expands expandable tokens instead of gathering them. Gathering a key ends when finding a comma or an equal sign or when all tokens of the list are gathered.  If gathering a key ends due to finding a comma, the next key is gathered. If gathering a key ends due to finding an equal sign, the corresponding value is gathered.

How should gathering tokens for a value  be done? You could say, just gather tokens unexpanded until either reaching the next comma (not nested in explicit catcode1/2 character tokens) or having gathered all tokens of the list.

But - if it is about arbitrary input by arbitrary users you have to reckon with everything - how do you handle the case that a user gets the idea to have a macro in the value-part, whose expansion contains a leading comma to end the value-part?

Something like this:

```latex
\def\MoreKeyVals{, keyc=valc, keyd=vald,}
\mycommand{keya=vala, keyb=valb \MoreKeyVals \keye=vale}
```

If something like this is also considered, the question arises how an algorithm for gathering tokens belonging to a value should decide whether to expand things or not to expand things?

Besides this exact specifications are needed regarding the removal of curly braces/surrounding spaces. E.g., shall surrounding spaces be removed before expansion or after expansion? That might make a difference in case expansion of expandable tokens yields space tokens.

If at some stage stringification of names of keys plays a rôle, one might ask the edge question of how to handle something like `\mycommand{{keya=vala, }keyb=valb}`?

Answer (score 2):

`\begin{advertisement}`

My `expkv` package has a built in grammar for key expansion, that grammar also supports expanding macros and using their replacement as additional key=value input. This is possible by prefixing the macro with `R:␣` (with `␣` being a space). In general the grammar scans for `<expansions>:␣` at the start of a key, and executes the `<expansions>`. For a complete list of defined expansion rules see the package documentation.

Caveat: Keys that contain `:␣` in their names become harder to input in `\ekvparse` (no problem in `\ekvset`), in which case you need to use `\ekvparse{<code1>}{<code2>}{: key: name: with: colons}` and the parsed key name will be `key: name: with: colons`.

To allow this mechanism in `l3keys` we wrap it by passing the key list once through `\ekvparse` to apply our expansion grammar, and the result gets forwarded to `\keys_set:nn`. We need two full expansions, the first for `\ekvparse` the second for our auxiliary macros to take effect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \ljr_set_keys_expanded:nn #1#2
  {
    \exp_args:Nne \keys_set:ne {#1}
      { \ekvparse \__ljr_set_keys_expanded:n \__ljr_set_keys_expanded:nn {#2} }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_set:nn { ne }
\cs_new:Npn \__ljr_set_keys_expanded:n #1
  { , { \exp_not:n {#1} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__ljr_set_keys_expanded:nn #1#2
  { , { \exp_not:n {#1} } = { \exp_not:n {#2} } }
\keys_define:nn { test }
  {
    key1 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key2 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key3 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key4 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key5 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key6 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \mycommand {m}
  { \ljr_set_keys_expanded:nn { test } {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mycommand{key1=val1,key2=val2,key3=val3,key4=val4,key5=val5,key6=val6}

\def\mymacroa{key3=val3,key4=val4}

\mycommand{key1=val1,key2=val2,R: \mymacroa,key5=val5,key6=val6} % error

\def\mymacrob{key2=val2,R: \mymacroa,key5=val5}

\mycommand{key1=val1,R: \mymacrob,key6=val6} % error

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\end{advertisement}`

Answer (score 1):

Create a new expanded variant of `\keys_set:nx`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { test }
  {
    key1 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key2 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key3 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key4 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key5 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
    key6 .code:n = \tl_to_str:n {#1},
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_set:nn { nx }
\NewDocumentCommand \mycommand {m}
  {
    \keys_set:nx { test } { #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\mycommand{key1=val1,key2=val2,key3=val3,key4=val4,key5=val5,key6=val6}

\def\mymacroa{key3=val3,key4=val4}

\mycommand{key1=val1,key2=val2,\mymacroa,key5=val5,key6=val6}

\def\mymacrob{key2=val2,\mymacroa,key5=val5}

\mycommand{key1=val1,\mymacrob,key6=val6}

\end{document}
```

Comment: General `x`-expanding things is probably not what you want...

Comment: @Skillmon I may not fully understand the question. So some case you don't want the expanding happens?

Comment: well, your solution fully expands everything, and now an unexperienced user is required to always put `\unexpanded` around or `\noexpand` before the stuff he doesn't want to expand, for the convenience that sometimes this does the right thing...

Comment: @Skillmon OK, I understand what do you mean. This may raise other issues in general.