# Macro in mandatory argument of tblr of tabularray does not work

Tags: tables, macros, expansion, tabularray

Minimal working example:

```tex
%! TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pyluatex}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

\let\rows\relax
\begin{python}
print("\\global\\def\\rows{Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Delta \\\\  Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta & Theta \\\\ Iota & Kappa & Lambda  & Mu \\\\  Nu & Xi & Omicron & Pi \\\\}")
\end{python}

\let\trivgroups\relax
\begin{python}
mystr = ""
for i in range(1,5):
  mystr += 'cell{'+str(i)+'}{'+str(i)+'} = {red4},'
print("\\global\\def\\trivgroups{"+mystr+"}")
\end{python}

\ExplSyntaxOff
% This works
% \begin{tblr}[expand=\rows]{colspec={|c|c|c|c|},
%     cell{1}{1}={red4},
%     cell{2}{2}={red4},
%     cell{3}{3}={red4},
%     cell{4}{4}={red4}
% }
\begin{tblr}[expand=\rows]{colspec={|c|c|c|c|},\trivgroups}
\rows
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Compilation still works

```
> lualatex --output-format=pdf --shell-escape pythontex-tabularray.tex
```

However, no colour in the output:

[image]

The commented version gives

[image]

Follow-up question of [Generate rows for tabularray with pyluatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654206/generate-rows-for-tabularray-with-pyluatex) with possible related questions:

- [tabularray: Expand multiple macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617961/tabularray-expand-multiple-macros)
- [tabularray: Reading a table stored in a macro by catchfile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604228/tabularray-reading-a-table-stored-in-a-macro-by-catchfile)
- [Misplaced alignment tab character &. with tabularray and expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648904/misplaced-alignment-tab-character-with-tabularray-and-expl3?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What is the best way to expand macros inside keyval input in expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648226/what-is-the-best-way-to-expand-macros-inside-keyval-input-in-expl3)

**UPDATE**

Before I used the new environment  `exptblr` from the answer by egreg, I could rotate the text in the header row as following:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pyluatex}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{makecell} 
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}
\setlength\rotheadsize{5cm}
\renewcommand\theadfont{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exptblr}{O{}m}
 {
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:N \begin{tblr}
    [\exp_not:n{#1}]
    {#2}
   }
 }
 {
  \end{tblr}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\let\rows\relax
\begin{python}
print("\\global\\def\\rows{Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Delta \\\\ Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta & Theta \\\\ Iota & Kappa & Lambda  & Mu \\\\ Nu & Xi & Omicron & Pi \\\\}")
\end{python}

\begin{python}
mystr = ""
for i in range(2,5):
  mystr += 'cell{'+str(i)+'}{'+str(i)+'} = {red4},'
\end{python}

\begin{tblr}[expand=\rows]{
  colspec={|c|c|c|c|},
  cell{1}{2-Z} = {halign=c,cmd=\rothead},
  hlines,vlines,
  % \py{mystr},
}
\diagbox[height=4cm,width=4cm]{subgroups $H$}{supergroups $G$} &
G1 Very Long & G2 Very Long & G3 Very Long \\
\rows
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But when I now use the new environment `exptblr`, I get following error:

```
! Use of \@gape doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...

l.45 }

?
```

Comment: Unrelated: You can omit `\let\command\relax`. I guess it's a PythonTeX pattern. PyLuaTeX doesn't need it because it does everything in a single run.

Comment: Ah this is an issue with fragile macro I think. In any case LJR has the functional package which aims to simplify expansion issues (personal opinion: I think the idea is good, but I don't like the implementation & the user manual currently does a not-very-good job teaching non-expert users I think.) Proper use of `evalWhole` and `tlUse` should work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tblr` doesn't expand macros in its mandatory argument.

You can define a new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pyluatex}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exptblr}{O{}m}
 {
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:N \begin{tblr}
    [\exp_not:n{#1}]
    {#2}
   }
 }
 {
  \end{tblr}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\let\rows\relax
\begin{python}
print("\\global\\def\\rows{Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Delta \\\\ Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta & Theta \\\\ Iota & Kappa & Lambda  & Mu \\\\ Nu & Xi & Omicron & Pi \\\\}")
\end{python}

\let\trivgroups\relax
\begin{python}
mystr = ""
for i in range(1,5):
  mystr += 'cell{'+str(i)+'}{'+str(i)+'} = {red4},'
print("\\global\\def\\trivgroups{"+mystr+"}")
\end{python}

\begin{exptblr}[expand=\rows]{colspec={|c|c|c|c|},\trivgroups}
\rows
\end{exptblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As [user187803](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/263192/user187803) points out in [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654222/macro-in-mandatory-argument-of-tblr-of-tabularray-does-not-work/654234?noredirect=1#comment1630485_654234) this can be simplified with `\py{mystr}`. I added also a couple of changes: `\let\rows\relax` is not needed and `\global\def` can be `\gdef`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pyluatex}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exptblr}{O{}m}
 {
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:N \begin{tblr}
    [\exp_not:n{#1}]
    {#2}
   }
 }
 {
  \end{tblr}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
print("\\gdef\\rows{Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Delta \\\\ Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta & Theta \\\\ Iota & Kappa & Lambda  & Mu \\\\ Nu & Xi & Omicron & Pi \\\\}")
\end{python}

\begin{python}
mystr = ""
for i in range(1,5):
  mystr += 'cell{'+str(i)+'}{'+str(i)+'} = {red4},'
\end{python}

\begin{exptblr}[expand=\rows]{colspec={|c|c|c|c|},\py{mystr}}
\rows
\end{exptblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To simplify it, you could even replace `\trivgroups` with `\py{mystr}`

Comment: @egreg: Thank you for your answer. However, I encountered now an issue when using `\rothead` for the cells in the header row. Expansion in LaTeX feels very complicated (even with LaTeX 3 which tries to simplify it). Can you have a look at the added example in my question?

Comment: @Hotschke Expansion is complicated with `tabularray`.

Comment: Should I use something else? I liked the user interface of tabularray. I want to create a matrix similar to this one https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Z2%5E4;_Lattice_of_subgroups_Hasse_diagram_adjacency_matrix.svg from a graphml. The python code is finished. I only need a suitable tool to create a large matrix with row and column headers typeset in LaTeX. Would you recommend tikz-matrix?

Comment: @Hotschke Without seeing the problematic table, I can't help much. And your present question seems not to address the real problem; but from the image I cannot see any usage of `\rothead`.

Comment: I am confused: the added image to the question contains rotated text in the header row. The strings `G <N> Very Long` are rotated. Do you really not see it?

Comment: @Hotschke Oh, the image in the question, not the one at Wikimedia! Try with `\noexpand\rothead`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, that did. It's easier than one expects. The LaTeX error message was misleading. But knowing the context what the new env does, the fix seems very obvious. Thanks for all the help. Do you have a preferred tool to create a large matrix like the one on wikimedia but with LaTeX labels in header rows/columns. The author of tabularray already said that from a performance view one should look for something else.